# Unity: Can we not change Animator State inside Update?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, events

```
void Update () {

        if (goright == true) {
            rig.velocity = new Vector2 (m.movespeed, rig.velocity.y);
            m.anim.SetInteger ("State", 1); 
        }

        if (goleft == true) {
            rig.velocity = new Vector2 (-m.movespeed, rig.velocity.y);
            m.anim.SetInteger ("State", 1);
        }
    }

    public void ondownMoveLeft(){

        goleft = true;
    }

    public void ondownMoveRight(){

        goright = true;
    }

    public void onupMoveLeft(){

        m.anim.SetInteger ("State", 0);
        goleft = false;
    }

    public void onupMoveRight(){

        m.anim.SetInteger ("State", 0);
        goright = false;
    }
```

i am using this code to move my character using UI buttons with the help of Event Triggers. i set it to change the animation from idle to running or from State 0 to 1 when the player moves and it does works that way but the problem is once it goes into State 1 it never comes back to State 0 but it should since i am setting the State back to 0 when the `OnPointerUp` trigger gets activated. am i missing something?

`OnPointerDown` is calling its respective ondown method and `OnPointerUp` is calling its respective onup method. for eg, when you press the left button it calls `OnPointerDown` which is set to call the method ondownMoveLeft.

i also checked with `Debug.Log` and everything is being executed but still the animation State is not changing.

Comment: What `OnPointerUp` trigger? I don't see it in your code

Comment: its respective "onup" method.

Comment: You mean `onupMoveRight` etc.? How are they being called? They are not part of `MonoBehaviour` so where are you calling them?

Comment: i am using Event Triggers on each UI button with both OnPointerUp and OnPointerDown events. then using them i call the respective method in this script.

Comment: And are they being called properly? Are the `m.anim.SetInteger ("State", 1);` being executed afterwards? Based on this code sample it will be hard to really help you - you need to use a debugger anyway.

Comment: this is all the code i could provide really because everything else happens from inside the inspector i will show you see this: https://s27.postimg.org/eohbv3gvn/Untitledfd.png
my player moves so my code does work its just that the State doesnt change to 0.

Comment: Well at this point I can primarily recommend using a debugger, breakpoints and maybe `Debug.Log` - it's a better approach anyway

Comment: i just checked with Debug.Log and everything is being executed but still the animation State is not changing.

Comment: Where are you placing the debug log? You *always*  reset your your state during `Update`, so in reality, `State` is always set/reset to `1`.

Comment: no it doesn't get set back to 1 since it doesn't go through that if statement(confirmed through debug log too) if the button is not pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use Mecanim you need to have two transitions, one from state 0 to state 1 and another from state 1 to state 0.